# How to catch Prisma's interactive transactions errors?

Tags: javascript, crash, try-catch, prisma

How do I catch this exception, right now its crashing the app.

[image: my code]

The Prisma docs say:
[image: docs]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.